# Image in Excel REport in openERP

Tags: python, report, odoo

I am working with excel report in **Open ERP** with **report_aeroo** module.
I want to put an image on my Excel Report; is any way to do this?

For example, I am generating a report of "employee Details" in HR module and I want an image of the Employee in report; how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use aeroo/report_openoffice since a long time but if I remember well you should use 'asimage'. Find its signature [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kndati/aeroo/trunk/view/head:/report_aeroo/ExtraFunctions.py#L297). Note that the method is '_asimage' but is assigned to the report as 'asimage', so that you have to do 'asimage(myobj.image_field,...)

Comment: ya thnks mr. simahawk i find out that function but now here i have new problem when there is a multiple images all are blur and doesnt seems properly. how can i set proper image size in ods file??

Comment: look at the signature of that method: you should be able to pass height/width to it.

Comment: no those are already calculate in it...

Comment: that's the default. you can force them. what's the problem then?

Comment: In Excel sheet when data comes photos are overlapped about it what can i do by changing size its not done

Comment: then I guess you have to properly set the height of the cell that will contain the image within the template itself. AFAIK this cannot be done without knowing the final size of the image.

Comment: the question here changed so, pls, if u need help for this other probl  close this one by marking the 1st answer as correct and ask another question about images overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a "frame" and set the name as ":image asimage(myobj.image_field,...)", as explained by Alistek here http://www.alistek.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=385